# Using object types with Jasmine's toHaveBeenCalledWith method

Tags: javascript, tdd, bdd, jasmine

I've just started using Jasmine so please forgive the newbie question but is it possible to test for object types when using `toHaveBeenCalledWith`?

```
expect(object.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith(instanceof String);
```

I know I could this but it's checking the return value rather than the argument.

```
expect(k instanceof namespace.Klass).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`toHaveBeenCalledWith` is a method of a spy. So you can only call them on spy like described in the [docs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies):

```
// your class to test
var Klass = function () {
};

Klass.prototype.method = function (arg) {
  return arg;
};


//the test
describe("spy behavior", function() {

  it('should spy on an instance method of a Klass', function() {
    // create a new instance
    var obj = new Klass();
    //spy on the method
    spyOn(obj, 'method');
    //call the method with some arguments
    obj.method('foo argument');
    //test the method was called with the arguments
    expect(obj.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo argument');   
    //test that the instance of the last called argument is string 
    expect(obj.method.calls.mostRecent().args[0] instanceof String).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: Andreas, is there any reason you added `.toBeTruthy()`? It seems like that is unnecessary.

Comment: @gwg `expect(foo)` without a matcher is a no-op; the line would do nothing without the `toBeTruthy()` call. See http://jsfiddle.net/2doafezv/2/ for proof.

Comment: This is out of date; `obj.method.mostRecentCall` needs to become [`obj.method.calls.mostRecent()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Other_tracking_properties) in Jasmine 2.0. Also, using `jasmine.any()`, as described in the other answer, is clearer and cuter. Finally, this answer takes a while to get to the point; essentially everything you wrote besides `expect(obj.method.mostRecentCall.args[0] instanceof String).toBeTruthy();` isn't really needed to explain yourself.

Answer (score 128):

I've discovered an even cooler mechanism, using [`jasmine.any()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_<code>jasmine.any</code>), as I find taking the arguments apart by hand to be sub-optimal for legibility.

In CoffeeScript:

```
obj = {}
obj.method = (arg1, arg2) ->

describe "callback", ->

   it "should be called with 'world' as second argument", ->
     spyOn(obj, 'method')
     obj.method('hello', 'world')
     expect(obj.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(String), 'world')
```

Comment: jasmine.any(Function) is handy, too

Comment: Noticed that it also works inside on references. for example:
`expect(obj.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith({done: jasmine.any(Function)})`. Very useful.

Comment: As of the time of this writing, Jasmine does not check for the same instance of `new String('world')` when using `toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)`. [Click here](https://medium.com/@fagnerbrack/mocking-can-lean-to-nondeterministic-tests-4ba8aef977a0) to understand why that is important.

Comment: Had to check if a callback function was called, `jasmin.any(Function)` saved my life, thank you